# Click change Url laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

How to debug

when I click this

`<li><a href="{{ url('promotion') }}">Promotion</a></li>`

It'll go to  `en/promotion` page

but after I do somthing not sure what I do It change to `/promotion`

any idea how to debug this

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Please add more info and what you want actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravel's [URL Default Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#default-values) for this. It allows you set a default value like the 'en' so you don't have to write it everytime and you would be able to use `url('test2')` to get `en/test2`

Comment: Are you calling the default value method from the route middleware so it's consistent?

Comment: It's not also a good advice to change your question completely in case of those in similar situations in future. Next time just indicate an update in the question and add your new situation.

Comment: here is my route     Route::get('/{url}', 'MenuController@menu');

Comment: I believe you need to configure your route to include the default value you've set above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to be able to have different languages in your website, but don't want to manage this manually on every redirect. You either need to write your own middleware to do this or use a package. 
I would recommend the latter. In my projects I'm using [this one](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization), there are others out there, you can find one that suits your needs.

This package has the ability to do exactly what you want - it rewrites your URL to include the language parameter.